# How to use Mysql SUM with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join

I have the following tables:

**`purchase_tbl`**

```
id | productId | purchaseQuantity 
---+-----------+-----------------
1  | 1         | 30
2  | 2         | 30
3  | 1         | 10
4  | 2         | 10
```

**`sale_tbl`**

```
id | productId | saleQuantity
---+-----------+-------------
1  | 1         | 10
2  | 2         | 10
3  | 1         | 10
4  | 2         | 10
5  | 1         | 10
6  | 2         | 10
```

I need to get the output as this one:

```
productId | totalPurchasedQuantity| totalSaleQuantity
----------+-----------------------+------------------
1         | 40                    | 30
2         | 40                    | 30
```

I'm using this query and how to get the desired result?

```
SELECT purchase_tbl.productId
    , SUM(purchase_tbl.purchaseQuantity) AS totalPurchaseQuantity
    , SUM(sale_tbl.saleQuantity) AS totalSaleQuantity
FROM purchase_tbl
JOIN sale_tbl
    ON purchase_tbl.productId = sale_tbl.productId
GROUP BY purchase_tbl.productId
```

Current output

```
productId | totalPurchaseQuantity | totalSaleQuantity
----------+-----------------------+------------------
1         | 120                   | 60
2         | 120                   | 60
```

Comment: what is the problem with the query, it looks fine to me

Comment: @Ravi query is fetching two rows with totalPurchasedQuantity as 120 and totalSaleQuantity as 60

Comment: can you show your exact output, which you are getting now?

Comment: @Ravi updated the question with the current output

Comment: I wouldn't be comfortable assuming every purchased product has a sales product.

Comment: @P.Salmon , a `full outer join` is the way.

Comment: @danihp Is a left join is enough? Because products not in the purchase table will not be available for sale. Products in sale_tbl always have an entry in purchase_tbl

Comment: @danihp a full outer join would be how I would go it if mysql had such a thing, or the next best thing a simulation of such.

Comment: @srndesignz there is no mention of time in the question but imagine if you had a sale in month 2 where the item was purchased in month 1 (and no purchases in month 2) or you had to adapt the left join query for a more time granular analysis.

Comment: @srndesignz There may be some added value in potentially discovering unexpected results(sales without purchases which is what you are discovering with a left join), but you know your data and requirement best.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, completely forgot that. Thank you :) full outer join is the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better group then in separate query, as table have multiple records for each product, which getting cross product.

```
SELECT purchase.productId, totalPurchaseQuantity, totalSaleQuantity
FROM
(SELECT purchase_tbl.productId
    , SUM(purchase_tbl.purchaseQuantity) AS totalPurchaseQuantity
FROM purchase_tbl
GROUP BY purchase_tbl.productId) purchase
INNER JOIN
(SELECT sale_tbl.productId
    , SUM(sale_tbl.saleQuantity) AS totalSaleQuantity
FROM sale_tbl
GROUP BY sale_tbl.productId
) sale ON sale.productId= purchase.productId;
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd do the aggregation once, in the super query

Comment: @Strawberry But, we don't have unique value in each tables, which causing the wrong output

Comment: I can't see that that would matter

Comment: @Strawberry hmm.. let me think. Just for side note, i hope, you might have noticed OP has written a sql query in his question (which is similar to what you are saying), but not getting correct output.

Comment: I disagree. It's very different

Comment: @Strawberry: Maybe you should post your solution as an answer, for I don't understand what you mean either. Ravi's query is perfect in joining purchase sum per product with sales sum per product. I don't see what you could possibly do better. (Well, except for better outer joining the sales in order to get products purchased but not sold yet.)

Comment: @Strawberry I would like to see, if we can have better solution.  I can't think anything other than in-line SELECT query (as a possible solution), which I feel would be not better than this.

Comment: I miss a full outer join also coalesces in this query.

Comment: @ravi your answer whilst getting the desired result will only pick where there are purchases with sales. It won't pick purchases without sales or sales without purchases.OP has had a think (see comments) and seems to think a full outer join is now the way to go.

Comment: @P.Salmon i didn't get you. As per original question, I remember, OP hasn't mentioned any other requirement. IMO, If OP is facing some other issue, then he has to create new post with the details issue.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain your expected result you have to do the aggregation on the individual table before joining them. Your query with be like:

```
SELECT A.productId, A.totalpurchaseQuantity, B.totalsaleQuantity
FROM
(SELECT productId, SUM(purchaseQuantity) 
   totalpurchaseQuantity FROM purchase_tbl 
    GROUP BY productId) A JOIN 
(SELECT productId, SUM(saleQuantity) 
   totalsaleQuantity FROM sale_tbl 
    GROUP BY productId) B ON
A.productId=B.productId;
```

Comment: thank you :) got the desired result after making a change. Changed id in the first subquery to productId

Comment: Ah, I corrected my answer, the idea remains the same.